# How to resize images according to user input to prevent overflowing on web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, html-table

I have a table which could contain 1 to 12 images depending on user input. If there is one image then it'll show up in the table nicely. However, if there are 12 images, it'll stretch vertically downwards until I need to scroll down to view the rest of the images.

Is there a way to dynamically resize the images such that no scrolling is required?

What it looks like with

5 images:

[image]

12 images:

[image]

This is the current table I have and I use a JavaScript to fill in the images

```
<table id="first">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li><img id="firstL1"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL2"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL3"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL4"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL5"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL6"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL7"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL8"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL9"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL10"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL11"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstL12"></li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td><ul></ul></td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li><img id="firstR1"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR2"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR3"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR4"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR5"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR6"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR7"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR8"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR9"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR10"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR11"></li>
                        <li><img id="firstR12"></li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your table takes height 100% of the screen

`var totalHeight = window.innerHeight,
     imgLen = $('table img').length;`

then
`$('table img').height(totalHeight / imgLen + 'px');`

Comment: interesting. i'll try this out and tell you if it works

Comment: @CHEWWWWWWWWWW Great